# The line of freezing precipitation curling up the eastern seaboard

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've looked up *curl up* but still I can't quite understand which sense is intended here, I can guess though that it means we have some precipitation in that area. What does curl up imply in this phrase and why has the writer chosen it_ is it supposed to create an image in the listener's mind? If yes, what?

> [You can see the line of freezing precipitation curling up the eastern seaboard yesterday.](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1402/13/sn.01.html)

Comment: It's not a precise term. It indicates that the line of precipitation is not  straight but proceeds in a series of curved segments. Ivy can curl up a wall.

Comment: If you look at radar images of weather patterns, especially advancing low pressure systems, you will see how they appear to "curl" as they move.

Comment: I see. Then it describes the patterns. Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the patterns. It's not an armadillo or hedgehog, but an irregularly shaped line, whose shape is morphing in accelerated time, superimposed on the  map of the eastern seaboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already been answered well, but for what it's worth, this type of motion is perhaps most often applied to rising smoke. That may help you to visualize what is happening here.